# Xcode cannot run using the selected device (Weird error)

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

I'm trying to debug an application on my iphone. I was able to do it before I updated Facebook client library yesterday. After updating, something weird happened and now I got the "Xcode cannot run using the selected device" error.

[image: Error screenshot]

Error can be seen from the screenshot. Note that in the upper middle it says "Finished running FacebookSDK on baysungur's iPhone", which is weird because my app's name is different.

I tried some things like adding architectures to build settings, decreasing minimum deployment target, etc. They did not work.

Anyone has any idea?

I'm using Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4.1. I'm trying to connect to a iphone 4.

Note: I was able to connect to device before updating that facebook client.

edit: Well, a similar thing also happens for simulator. Now I basically can not debug my app in any way.

Comment: `I tried somet things like adding architectures to build settings` it didn't work ? Maybe you should try adding armv6 if it is an older device. I got this error when i tried running my app on iPhone 3GS, just added an armv6 architecture and got it working.

Comment: I'm using iphone4 to connect. I edited the question.

Comment: check to see if xcode supported iOS is installed on the device. also check if a valid provisional profile is installed. If you didn't update the iPhone iOS or xCode, try doing a restart or come back later. It happens with me sometimes, xcode simply denies to run on device while it actually runs other times.

Comment: I'm with tGilani - restart both the device and mac and give it another go.

Comment: No luck in restarting. I will try to delete and reinstall xcode.

Comment: Deleting and reinstalling did not work :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook library had a file named Info.plist, which caused xcode's head to be confused.

Weird thing is that I was seeing correct settings in project's settings. I mean everything seemed correct in that UI but appearantly xcode was using wrong Info.plist in action.

Deleting that second Info.plist solved the issue.

Comment: Do you know exactly which Info.plist you deleted, i.e. what was the path to it?

Comment: It should be under the directory in which you place your Facebook library. I don't remember the exact path to it, but searching under that parent directory should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Is device is connected in organizer? If yes then quit your xcode and also restart your device and choose valid provisioning profile and try again.

thanks

Comment: Yes, it's the right profile. Cause of the Issue was something different. I've written an answer.