# Cannot run on selected device IOS FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have this error  **"Xcode cannot run using the selected device. Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device"** in Xcode when i tried to run the app in Simulator or Device (i've tried in ios 5, 5.1, 6).

This happens after that i install the Facebook SDK 3.1 from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/downloads/)

i can't find any solution ... any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clear answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11936610/2025924
The file info.plist in FacebookSDK is conflicting with info.plist of the project.